# Two LoginUrl form authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, forms-authentication

I currently building web management system using mvc3

In my application i have system section that required login for only admin.
and presentation web that also have a sign in form for users that registered to the site.

i want to accomplish that when unregistered visitor try to enter action in controller he will redirect to Login View

but, when unregistered visitor try to enter action in system controller he will redirect to another login view.

is it posible?
I know that i can put this line in web.config

`<forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />`

but this line always redirect the user to the same login url

Can i put web.config inside folder inside View folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a custom Authorize attribute and override the [HandleUnauthorizedRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.handleunauthorizedrequest.aspx) in which you would redirect to some other login view. Then simply decorate the SystemController with this custom attribute instead of using the standard one which redirects to the url in web.config.

Answer (score 0):

loginUrl is used by [FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z8s9bze.aspx), but you can handle it by yourself using classic Response.Redirect after user authentication. What you can't do is show different login page for admin or normal user since you don't know which one is which until he logs in.